# c# Lambda expression, convert list<type1> to list<type2> using Automapper

Tags: c#, lambda

I've been working on this for most of the day and can't figure out how to create this into a simple Lambda expression:

```
    public IReadOnlyList<UserActivity> GetListOfUserActivities()
    {
        List<UserActivity> userActivities = new List<UserActivity>();
        List<Activity> activities = _activityDataAccess.GetActivities();
        foreach (var activity in activities)
        {
            UserActivity userActivity = _mapper.Map<UserActivity>(activity);
            userActivity.Parent = this;
            userActivities.Add(userActivity);
        }
        return userActivities;
    }
```

So in a nutshell:

1. I want to convert an Activity to a UserActivity
2. I'm using AutoMapper to do this; which works fine.
3. I then want to set a parent reference in the converted object to this, i.e. UserActivities; simply so I can use the UserActivities database access to provide a 'delete' method for a UserActivity.
4. I then want to return a IReadOnlyList.

This is where I got to:

```
activities
    .ConvertAll(act => _mapper.Map<UserActivity>(act))
    .Select(uac => uac.Parent = this).ToList();
```

But it's really not happy!

Comment: "It's really not happy" is not a valid problem statement.  Can you be more specific about the error (if any) you are getting or the difficulty you are having?

Comment: return (IReadOnlyList<UserActivity>) activities.ConvertAll(act => _mapper.Map<UserActivity>(act)).Select(uac => uac.Parent = this.ToList();

Suspicious type conversion or cast.

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate post I linked at the top of your question.

Comment: Its not the conversion of types, Automapper works perfectly. I just want a working lambda way to do what I'm doing in the for each.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's wrong with your original code?  Can't you just use that as-is?

Comment: Also, I still think you should read the duplicate.  There's some good advice there.

Comment: Erm, not sure you read it correctly: "I've been working on this for most of the day and can't figure out how to create this into a simple Lambda expression".

Comment: Your original code is not translatable into a lambda expression, not directly anyway.  You're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Also, can you please read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  It might help.

Comment: Harsh, but thanks for looking.

Comment: Just so you know, returning it as a IReadOnlyList doesn't in any way make it read only... if you want to ensure no one ever changes it, you need to do a bit more.

Comment: Thanks Blue, I realise it can be simply casted back but it shows the API user my intent. Don't want to create my own classes, that's more work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
activities
    .Select(act =>
    {
        var userActivity = _mapper.Map<UserActivity>(act);
        userActivity.Parent = this;
        return userActivity;
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite get what you're doing with `this`, but couldn't you:

Create a new constructor for `UserActivity` that takes a parameter for parent and the incoming `Activity` object, and does the mapping in there:

```
public UserActivity(Activity activity, Object parent){
    this = _mapper.Map<UserActivity>(activity);
    this.Parent = parent;
}
```

And then do a select in the lambda to new up the objects into a list:

```
var userActivities = activities.Select(i => new UserActivity(i, parentObject)); // parentObject == this?
```

Comment: I accept this answer because this brought me to the below solution, how, read below.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to be too clever (or not as the case maybe):

```
    public IReadOnlyList<UserActivity> GetListOfUserActivities()
    {
        List<UserActivity> userActivities = _activityDataAccess.GetActivities().ConvertAll(act => _mapper.Map<UserActivity>(act)).ToList();
        userActivities.ForEach(ua => ua.Parent = this);
        return userActivities;
    }
```

But thinking about Johnathan's post, i.e. breaking down the problem further, I realised that the above would work, just needed to break it down into two statements. Thanks.